# LWC Composition for fields inside a record-edit-form

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components

I have a `lightning-record-edit-form` with multiple `lightning-input-field`.

I'd like to put some of the `input-field` into a child component, say `childComponent`. The code is attached at the end.

However, the issue is that the `lightning-input-field` in `childComponent` does not render correctly. I assume the connection between `lightning-record-edit-form` and the API name in `field-name` are broken.

How to fix it?

**The code for parent component:**
`field3__c` and `field4__c` do not show correctly.

```
<template>
  <lightning-record-edit-form  object-api-name={objectApiName} record-id={recordId}>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="field1__c"></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="field2__c"></lightning-input-field>
    <c-child-component></c-child-component>
  </lightning-record-edit-form
</template>
```

**The code for child component:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="field3__c"></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="field4__c"></lightning-input-field>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `lightning-input-field` as standalone component. The component always works within the context of a `lightning-record-edit-form`. Without the details of the `object-api-name` defined in the `lightning-record-edit-form`, there will be no way to link the `field-name` on `lighnting-input-field` back to that SObject.

This is from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation):

> To create a record edit layout, use this component with `lightning-record-edit-form` and pass in a record ID and object API name.
>
> To create a record create layout, use this component with `lightning-record-edit-form` and pass in the object API name of the record you're creating.

Comment: I understand `lightning=-input-field` doesn't work alone. In my special case, it always sits inside of the `lightning-record-edit-form`. My custom object has over 100 custom fields. Putting all fields into one gigantic page in one LWC makes me worry how clean(messy) the html page looks like.

Comment: It actually doesn't sit inside the `lightning-record-edit-form`. Because every component added sits within its own [shadow tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_dom) and in this case the boundary is the child component.

Comment: I see, that might be a hard wall. In my case, there are 100+ custom fields in this `record-edit-form`, I wish to break them down into multiple child pages/modules so it is not a HTML with 1000+ line of markups. Is there an alternative to achieve it?

Comment: You may like to use [`lightning-record-form`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) here instead. That will also take care of FLS and sharing.

Comment: Thanks for recommending. Unfortunately, `lightning-record-form` doesn't fit my situation, there are custom look&feel and error-handling only `lightning-edit-form` supports.

Comment: In that case unfortunately you may be out of luck here.

Comment: For anyone else with a lot of fields, when I find a better approach is to build the fields names and rules as a JavaScript array of objects. In HTML inside the record edit form you can do a for loop to output each of the fields, then you're driving all your metadata from JavaScript. You can take it further and use a custom object to define all these fields and a wire method to grab those settings.