# Populate lightning-input-field from user selection of another field

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC where I want to populate

```
<lightning-input-field field-name={customlookup} required="true"></lightning-input-field>
```

What I was thinking was that when a user selects a value from the lookup, I could assign the input field like this:

```
this.selectedId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id; 
this.customlookup= this.selectedId;
```

Put I do not see the selected lookup value being rendered on the LWC input field.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

lightning-input-field needs to be wrapped around
**lightning-record-edit-form** and specified with **object-api-name**="YourObjectAPIName".

If you are trying to use the component without using lightning-record-edit-form , the component will not be able to identify with which object the fieldName is associated to.

You can take reference from answer here - [LWC Composition for fields inside a record-edit-form](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265807/lwc-composition-for-fields-inside-a-record-edit-form)

and read documentation -  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation

Comment: Hello Ashay.  The lightning-input-field is wrapped but the lookup is not.  Trying to grab the selected lookup value and populate the lightning-input-field.  Or use the lookup value when a user saves a record.  Based on the lightning-input-field field values and the selected lookup value.  The selected lookup value is a required field for the record that will be created based on user input.  
Thanks